# paypal.HostedFields.isEligible() returns False always : Paypal Debit/Credit Card Payment

Tags: python-3.x, django, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I want to include debit/credit card payments powered by papal for my website, I am following the guide as per

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/

but for the code

```
paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()
```

I always get the false or undefined as error, may be I skipped something, please help.

Comment: Have you requested advanced debit and credit card processing for your sandbox business account? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/#1-enable-your-account

Comment: I do have business and advanced credit card processing enabled, its always false as well

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. did you find a solution for this? everybody is referring to documentation and asking if it's enabled for advanced payments but I can't find any guide on how to enable it.

Comment: For us it took a few days, before it started working - we contacted the support, but they told us sandbox environments do not need manual approval.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/SDKs/PayPal-Checkout-Hosted-Fields/td-p/2288953) answer on the Paypal community.

"In my case, I was using a personal account as a developer account. When I created sandbox credentials from the Business account it started to work. So make sure,

1. Developer account is linked/created with the business account
2. Sandbox account is created from that.
3. Sandbox account should also be a business account and it should be enabled for advanced payments ( Using this link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/#enable-your-account )"

Answer (score 0):

Here the keypoints:

- You need a business account to use advanced payments.
- You don't need to have a real business account when working in the sandbox environment: you can create a fake business account in the sandbox and use it.
- You need to ask for approval to use the advanced payments. This request must be done separately for sandbox and production accounts.
- When loading the Javascript SDK be sure to not pass the `disable-funding=card` parameter, otherwise `isEligible()` will return false even if your account has been approved!