# PayPal Advanced Credit Card Payments - paypal.HostedFields.isEligible() returns False

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate PayPal's advanced credit card payments into my web app but the below code always returns false.

```
paypal.HostedFields.isEligible()
```

I've checked the account settings about 100 times. I've enabled all credit card payments, created sandbox businesses accounts and etc. still getting the same error.
FYI.. paypal.Buttons works without any issues.
Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: This may be relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936468/paypal-hostedfields-iseligible-returns-false-always-paypal-debit-credit-card

Comment: Show your code, including the sandbox client ID and all values (no variables that do not have a specified value)